# MongoDB collection locking - how does it work?

Tags: mongodb, locking

I have not so big collection, that has about 500k records, but it's mission critical.

I want to add one field and remove another one. I was wondering would it lock that collection from inserting/updating (I really don't want any downtime).

I've made an experiment, and it looks that it doesn't block it:

```
// mongo-console 1
 use "my_db"

// add new field
db.my_col.update(
    {},
    { $set:
      { foobar : "bizfoo"}
    },
    { multi: true}
    );

// mongo-console 2
use "my_db"
db.my_col.insert({_id: 1, foobar: 'Im in'});
db.my_col.findOne({_id: 1});

=>{ "_id" : 1, "foo" : "bar" }
```

Although I don't really understand why, because db.currentOp() shows that there are Write locks on it.

Also on the production system I have replica set, and I was curious how does it impact the migration.
Can someone answer these questions, or point me to some article where it's nicely explained.
Thanks!

(MongoDB version I use is 2.4)

Comment: Databases are designed to add/remove fields quickly and as it runs. As long as adding or removing a single record won't break anything with the application that is running using the DB. Adding or removing should not cause any downtime.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I guess this is what I expected, but is there any good paper on that matter? I kinda understand that this is easy for RDBMS, but I thought that mongodb has to touch all documents in the collection, and that operation is not so straightforward...

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB 2.4 locks on the database level per shard.  You mentioned you have a replica set.  Replica sets have no impact on the locking.  Shards do.  If you have your data sharded, when you perform an update, the lock will only lock the database on the shard where the data lives.  If you don't have your data sharded, then the database is locked during the write operation.

In order to see impact, you'll need a test that does a significant amount of work.

You can read more at:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+does+concurrency+work

Comment: But I have one more question, maybe you know the answer. I was wondering why I'm able to make inserts on the collection that seems to have a write lock? Am I missing something here?

Comment: As Adam mentioned above, the operations are typically very quick, how long does the update operation take?  MongoDB does have lock yielding such that if the data being operated on by the update is not in memory, it will yield it's lock to an insert who's page is in memory.  I'm honestly not very familiar with this logic and when locks will be yielded and when they won't...but, assuming your update operation takes a while, it could be this lock yielding that is allowing your insert to take place.